# How to seralize json document to java object automatically (using reflection)

Tags: java, json, api, jackson

I have a simple API on nodejs that stores MongoDB documents. I have an API endpoint that retrieves documents in a json array.

I want to implement a client for this API in Java. Since Java supports reflection, I should't need to map each json document from the array into a java object with the same fields. There must be a way that simply maps one to another. However, it must support nested objects. Here's my object in Java:

```
public class Order {
    public Boolean deleted;
    //Use only when updating an order, _id is mongo's _id of order to be updated
    public String _id;
    static public class Product {
        public String name;
        public Integer quantity;
        public Float price;
    }
    public String clientName;
    public String clientPhone;
    public Integer seller_id;
    public Integer order_id;
    public String observations;
    public ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    public Float total;
}
```

The Json Array that I receive from the API will have the same members: `clientName`, `clientPhone`, `products`, etc. I just need to map the Json Array element to Order.

There's a library that supports reflection (Jackson) and gives me a way to do the inverse: Order to Json, but I couldn't find a way to do what I want.

Comment: Jackson supports both serialization and deserialization. So does [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jackson, you can convert json to java object in following way.

```java
//json variable is the String represenating the json you have received from API
Order order = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Order.class);
```

For more examples you can check [Jackson examples](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization)